# How to show the unhighlighted/ not selected data points on scatter plots when using brush/group in dc.js? And is multiple brushes possible in dc.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I have two questions.

1. Is it possible to still show the not selected data in corresponding scatter plot. Where there can be two scatters around the selected data points that the other data points stay or if there can be a color.
2. Is it possible to have multiple brushes in dc.js. Where I can select one part of data and do that again on another place in the same scatter plot.

**For question 1**

This is before the selection:

[image: This before the selection]

This after selection on graph. I would still like the not selected one to still appear:

[image: This after selection on the graph. I would still like the not selected ones to still appear]

What I would like for question 1

[image: what I would like for question 1]

Here is my code sample:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>dc.js - Scatter Plot Brushing Example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/dc.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<script type="text/javascript" src="header.js"></script>

  <p>Brush on one chart to see the points filtered on the other.</p>
  <div id="test1"></div>
  <div id="test2"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/d3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/crossfilter.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/dc.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
var chart1 = dc.scatterPlot("#test1");
var chart2 = dc.scatterPlot("#test2");
var data = "x,y,z\n" +
    "1,1,3\n" +
    "5,2,11\n" +
    "13,13,13\n"+
    "5,3,20\n"+
    "12,12,10\n"+
    "3,6,8\n"+
    "15,2,9\n"+
    "8,6,14\n"+
    "1,4,9\n"+
    "8,8,12\n";
var data = d3.csvParse(data);
data.forEach(function (x) {
    x.x = +x.x;
    x.y = +x.y;
    x.z = +x.z;
});
var ndx = crossfilter(data),
    dim1 = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
        return [+d.x, +d.y];
    }),
    dim2 = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
        return [+d.y, +d.z];
    }),
    group1 = dim1.group(),
    group2 = dim2.group();
chart1.width(300)
    .height(300)
    .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 20]))
    .yAxisLabel("y")
    .xAxisLabel("x")
    .clipPadding(10)
    .dimension(dim1)
    .excludedOpacity(0.5)
    .group(group1);
chart2.width(300)
    .height(300)
    .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 20]))
    .yAxisLabel("z")
    .xAxisLabel("y")
    .clipPadding(10)
    .dimension(dim2)
    .excludedColor('#ddd')
    .group(group2);
dc.renderAll();
  </script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Re: Q2: it has been requested but is not currently possible: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1288

Answer (score 1):

A1) That will be pretty difficult because `dc.js` sets the `d` of the paths of the not selected symbols in the other chart to `d="M0,0"`. That means no path at all and all the symbols are now in the origin of the chart.

**Edit**

Looking at the code and after a little experiment I found if you add these then the other dots are visible

```
.emptySize(3)
.emptyOpacity(0.5)
```

The name is not very explanatory.

Comment: Right, crossfilter doesn't remove empty bins by itself, so the dots do exist, you just have to add the right encoding. And yeah, it's not a great interface. Backward-compatible fixes are always welcome!

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there another interactive js you would recommend?